# Newline does not show the entire text in vaadin-text-field

Tags: javascript, polymer, vaadin, web-component

I have a string which is returned by a JAVA API as follows.

**String:**

```
var text = "Enjoy True Value Tuesday!\nExclusive Bhangra Class tomorrow at 7am.\nAlso get flat discount Rs.2500\/- on all memberships.\nFirst come First book.Limited 10 ";
```

When I set the text of the `vaadin-text-area` to this string it does not show the full text, as shown in the following image.

[image]

I also have tried to change the '\n' to 
 as suggested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v0y3xvpx/1/). But it did not solve the problem.
[image]

Can anyone please let me know what is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Almost seems like your text-area does not take/show more then 2 lines of text.
Please pass some more of the code.

Comment: It’s possible. Let me check

Comment: I went to https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-text-area/html-examples/text-area-demos and using the developer tools in Chrome I selected one of the `vaadin-text-area` elements, then in the console I typed `$0.value = "<your text>"`, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Ok, this is not related to newline. Apparently @xKean is right. This text-area is embeddeb into a vaadin-grid and its max-height is set . But not scrollbar appears in case of text overflow.

Comment: @ErikLumme, I have done as you said and I also set the readonly to false `$0.readOnly=true`. Now one can not scroll the text. Is there a way to display scroll bar when there is a large text?

Comment: @SudiptaRoy Is that specific to when it's inside a grid? In the examples I linked, a scroll bar appears when the text overflows (in the max-height example, or if I set `$0.style.height`), whether it's read-only or not.

Comment: @ErikLumme inmy case when I set the readOnly to true, no scrollbar apprears( in vaadin webpage) and you can not focus on the text , so the up/down key also doesn’t work

Comment: Ok, I have managed to solve it. This is not related to newline in any way, as mentioned in previous comments. After setting the text one needs to call `_updateHeight` method in `vaadin-text-area`. Hope this helps.